# ASP Classic XMLHTTP GET JSON

Tags: json, asp-classic, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to retrieve the output from the a URL using XMLHTTP GET:

The output in the browser when I hit the url directly is the following:

```
{
 "Titles": {
  "resultCount": 37680,
  "moreResources": true
 }
}
```

The ASP code on test.asp I am using is:

```
<%@language=JScript%>
<%
var objSrvHTTP;
objSrvHTTP = Server.CreateObject ("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0");
objSrvHTTP.open ("GET","http://someipaddress:8080/Publisher/Titles/Paging/0,0,tc?output=json", false);
objSrvHTTP.send ();
Response.ContentType = "application/json";
Response.Write (objSrvHTTP.responseText);
%>
```

The results displayed in browser from hitting test.asp is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>something</title>
</head>

<body>
{
"Titles": {
"resultCount": 37698,
"moreResources": true
}
}
</body>
</html>
```

I am looking to have just the data between the body tags returned, or even better just the value for "resultCount".  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the `HTML` markup, when reading `JSON` data it should be nothing but valid `JSON` in the request response.